# Displaying a summary of activity for the day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have a model called Thing and I want to see, in the homepage, how many Things were created each day.

I came up with this:

```
Thing.order("created_at desc").where(created_at: (Date.today - 1.month)..Date.today).group_by{|s| s.created_at.to_date}
```

which I can call `each_pair` on and do my thing.

However, this seems highly inefficient: this is in the homepage for all users to see, and it only changes a few times a day.

I feel like I should be doing some kind of caching, but I don't know what pattern to use.

Answer (score 1):

Although I feel like that's not enough information to give you a complete answer, here's my take:

1. You can store the stats per day as a column in the db table for all but today's stats
2. Calculate it on the fly and use memcache or some other cache store. See fragment caching http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Example:

```
<% Order.find_recent.each do |o| %>
  <%= o.buyer.name %> bought <%= o.product.name %>
<% end %>

<% cache do %>
  All available products:
  <% Product.all.each do |p| %>
    <%= link_to p.name, product_url(p) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Definetly caching that section is a good idea, since it only have a few updates per day. A possible approach (with fragment caching):

In your view:

```
<% cache('homepage_things') do %>
  <% @things.each do |thing| %>
    <%= thing %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)

    if @thing.save
      expire_fragment('homepage_things')
      # other stuff
    else
      # other stuff
    end
  end
end
```